# DNS - Subdomain has Wildcard

Tags: dns

Is this a valid DNS entry

```
*.subdomain.tld
```

i.e.

```
*.dev.domain.com
```

Cheers

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is valid dns wildcard, i.e.:

```
*.subdomain.tld.  IN A 1.2.3.4
```

and any query for `<anything>.subdomain.tld` will be resolved to 1.2.3.4